# Creating 10 different figures in Matplotlib lib without creating them individually

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I'm trying to create a plot using Matplotlib that has two x-axes, top and bottom, and one y-axis. Then I want to divide this plot into 10 different figures. I'm trying to figure out how to do this without creating each figure individually.

For example: x-axis is miles 30 - 60, secondary x is the same as the primary axis, but units are feet. I don't want to display 30 miles on one graph. I want each graph to be only 3 miles.

Does anyone have an advise for this?

Comment: Please provide the data you are working with !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and edit your post.

Comment: Each figure or subplot in Matplotlib is separate plotting object.  You have to create each.  Why don't you want to create them individually?  Post a small working example, and maybe we can help you streamline the action.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? You'll have to figure out the formatting of course.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

X = np.arange(30, 61)
Y = np.cos(X*0.5)

n_plots = np.ptp(X) // 3  # 3 miles per subplot
XY_chunks = list(zip(np.array_split(X, n_plots), 
                     np.array_split(Y, n_plots)))

fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=n_plots, figsize=(15, 2), sharey='row')

for i in range(n_plots):
    XX, YY = XY_chunks[i]  # Unpack X and Y for this plot
    axs[i].plot(XX,YY)  # Plot miles
    ax2 = axs[i].twiny()  # This will be your feet axis
    ax2.set_xticklabels((XX*5280).round(), rotation=90)  # Convert to feet
    axs[i].set_xlabel('Miles')
    ax2.set_xlabel('Feet')

plt.show()
```

[image: Matplotlib graph with 10 subplots]